# How do I make transformation work using badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor library?

Tags: angular, cucumber, cypress, gherkin, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I've spent many hours on it already and it doesn't work as intended. Here's one of attempts to make it clear:

```js
// something.feature
Feature: asdf
  Scenario: asdf asdf
    # any of steps below called here gives the same error
    # When something "second parameter"
    When something option1 "second parameter"
    # When something secondOption "second parameter"
```

```js
// steps.ts
When('something {OptionType} {string}', (
  firstParameter: OptionType, 
  secondParameter: string) => {
    // todo
});
```

```js
// transformations.ts
import { defineParameterType } from '@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor';

export enum OptionType {
  defaultOption,
  option1,
  secondOption,
  blablabla,
}

defineParameterType({
  name: 'OptionType',
  regexp: /^(option1|secondOption|blablabla)?$/,
  transformer: (value: string) => {
    let result = OptionType.defaultOption;
    switch(value) {
      case "":
        result = OptionType.defaultOption;
        break;
      case "option1":
        result = OptionType.option1;
        break;
      case "secondOption":
        result = OptionType.secondOption;
        break;
      case "blablabla":
        result = OptionType.blablabla;
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error("No suitable option");
    }
    return result;
  },
});
```

So what I want is that I want first parameter to be optional so that if it's called as first call in feature file `firstParameter` has value `OptionType.defaultOption` and if there's some other option, then it has corresponding enum value.
I want to change second parameter to a class object later but I think that if I accomplish this enum thing - I'll handle class as well.

All my attempts failed so far. Right now it says that the step is missing implementation. When I tried to change `{OptionType}` to `(.*)` in the step definition - it gives the same error.

Any ideas on what's wrong here?

I'm using these versions:
"@angular/common": "15.1.1",
"@nrwl/cypress": "15.5.2",
"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^15.1.4",
"nx": "15.5.2".

Also path is not default `cypress/...`. It's placed inside a separate app. Not sure, but probably that could influence something as well?
I've imported step definitions and transformations so they are definitely not missing right now for cypress. But probably something else does?

Here's a [documentation](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/cucumber-basics.md#custom-parameter-types) on this topic but it seems that it's missing a more complete example or it's not designed to be used with nx and in a different folder then default `cypress` folder or everything above.

Also please note that "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor" library is an old outdated one. Currently ownership has changed and latest up to date library is "badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor". So when you write an answer please make sure it's not referring to the old one because it might not work any more.

P.S. This is not 100% actual code from my project. I've changed things to make sure I don't violate NDA.

Comment: ***step is missing implementation*** is the error? That seems to indicate file placement or configuration. Please advise where you have placed the step files, and what your configuration is. As @LeopardTanks says `defineParameterType` is not the way to overload the step and has nothing to do with this error.

Comment: This is not overloading. It's transformation. Specflow has it as well and it works without this hell I've been through trying to make it work. Also it's not a configuration of file placement because at first I made it work without parameters and it worked. Then I added simple `{string}` parameters and it worked. Then I tried to make it work with transformation and it doesn't. I want to pass a string in feature file and recieve custom object (class or enum) in method definition. `defineParameterType` seems to be the way to go. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the root cause of this error were `^` and `$` characters in the regex of `OptionType` in the `defineParameterType` call. Deleting them makes everything work.

Call of the step without specifying the first parameter still requires editing (like overloading of the step or removing 1 space from step definition string and adding a space instead to every option in `OptionType` regex) but it starts working.

My best guess is that "{OptionType}" part of the regex that goes as first parameter to `When` function is replaced by `OptionType` regex and as result there is this regex:

`something ^(option1|secondOption|blablabla)?$ ".*"`

So evantually since there are characters "^" and "$" in the middle of a regular expression - there's no way any string would match that. It's because those characters mean start and end of the string and they are placed in the middle.

So the result regex has to be like this to work:

`something (option1|secondOption|blablabla)? ".*"`

and regex parameter of `defineParameterType` has to be like this:

```
regexp: /(option1|secondOption|blablabla)?/,
```

Comment: I just ran your `defineParameterType` with `regexp: /^(option1|secondOption|blablabla)?$/,` and it passed the test.

Comment: And I used the two overloaded `When()` statements, it passes. But not when I use your single `When()` statement. Something smells.

Comment: @Charles.de.Pierrefonds ,  as I mentioned above, you need to edit it to make it work without overloading. Think of it as replacement of `{OptionType}` in step definition with `OptionType`'s regex. It's about spaces.

Comment: And I don't understand how could it pass with that regex with "^" and "$" characters. @Charles.de.Pierrefonds, did  you reload the page? I've noticed that when you edit feature files it reruns tests, but when I've been editing code it wasn't always rerunning tests again. Probably because I've written that enum and `defineParameterType` call in a separate file and then I import it. Besides, are you sure that transformation code was called? If you add some `console.log` there, can you see its output in a chrome console?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `defineParameterType` can do much for you here. The "name" parameter seems to correspond to one parameter name only, I can't see it resolving two parameters.

The error looks due to `When something "second parameter"` having just one parameter, and there is no matching pattern in `steps.ts`.

So, you could add an "overload" step definition

**steps.ts**

```js
// match first feature step
When('something {string}', (secondParameter: string) => {
  handleOptionType(OptionType.defaultOption, secondParameter)
}

// match other feature steps
When('something {OptionType} {string}', (firstParameter: OptionType, secondParameter: string) => {
  handleOptionType(firstParameter, secondParameter)
})

function handleOptionType(firstParameter: OptionType, secondParameter: string) {
  // todo
}
```

Comment: No, that's not the case. I'm aware of a possibility to overload it. But any of those steps in a feature file called alone gives that same error.